How to inject request to the HttpLogger in the express middleware example using "pino-http"?
I want to follow this example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-http#use-as-express-middleware
but I also want to provide the logger() call with the request object
Something like this:
const logger = require('pino-http')

const app = express()

app.use((req) => logger(req))

But it does not work (it crashes my server). Is it even possible? This logger function does not actually accept any argument, but I have my custom function (which eventually returns pino-http logger instance) where I want to provide this argument.
